# How to check which Python interpreter is used to run WSGI scripts in apache2?

Tags: python, apache, web, apache2, wsgi

For example, there're two versions of django (1.1, 1.4) installed on the server, and two versions of python(2.6,2.7) as well. Is there a way to check which version of python/library is being used by WSGI?

(in other words, is there a way to check which interpreter is used to run the scripts under `/etc/apache2/wsgis-available/` directory)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what I mean is how to check which interpreter is used to run the scripts under /etc/apache2/wsgis-available/ directory..

Comment: You mean by mod_wsgi?

Comment: I understood the question @Hanfei, its a pity about these nit pickers.

Answer (score 6):

Running `ldd` Or Dependency Walker against the mod_wsgi module will tell you which version of the Python library it was built against.

e.g.

```
ldd <PATH TO YOUR MOD_WSGI MODULE>/mod_wsgi.so
```

more documentation [here](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library)

Answer (score 0):

This and much more is all covered in the mod_wsgi documentation.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library